# $interval continues to run when I go from one state to other using route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have a application in which I have to show a page time-out timer progress bar. I am doing it using $interval. But When I go from one state to other the $interval doesn't get cleared and the shows the session time-out of the previous page. I am using the $interval function in a controller for timer functionality. I am also cancelling the same on page destroy. here is the below snippet,

```
$scope.obj.updateProgressBar = function () {
        $scope.obj.showTimer = true;
        intervalPromise =  $interval(function () {

            if ($scope.obj.currentTime < $scope.obj.max) {
                $scope.obj.currentTime += 1;
                $scope.obj.diff = $scope.obj.max - $scope.obj.currentTime;
                $scope.obj.m = ($scope.obj.diff / 60) >> 0;
                $scope.obj.s = ($scope.obj.diff - $scope.obj.m * 60) + '';
                $scope.obj.s = ($scope.obj.s).length >= 1 ? $scope.obj.s : '0';
            } else {
                $scope.obj.timeout=true;
                $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
                $scope.togglePopup();
                $scope.open('sm', 'sessionTimeoutTemplate');
            }
        }, 1000,timerDuration+1);
    };
    $scope.obj.updateProgressBar();

}
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
if(intervalPromise)
    $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
```

});

Please help me on this, what i can do to destroy the $interval.

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: does $destroy get called? if you set a break point what is the value of intervalPromise in the $destroy event?

Comment: does `updateprogressBar` get called more than once? if so you will only cancel the last interval , not prior ones